# Reversing COLUMN DATA by dynamically passing table name and Column Name

Tags: sql-server, dynamic

I want to reverse a COLUMN DATA dynamically by passing table name and Column Name

```
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME  NVARCHAR(300)   -- to pass table name dynamically
DECLARE @COLUMN_NAME NVARCHAR(300)   -- to pass column name dynamically

SET @TABLE_NAME = 'TEST1'   -- Passing table name
SET @COLUMN_NAME = 'SSN'    -- Passing column Name

DECLARE @OUTPUT NVARCHAR(MAX)   -- to pass the selected column data to update

SET @OUTPUT = 'SELECT'+' '+@COLUMN_NAME+' '+'FROM'+@TABLE_NAME

DECLARE @UPDATE_EXEC NVARCHAR(MAX)    -- To exec the Final update result 
SET @UPDATE_EXEC = 'UPDATE ['+@TABLE_Name + ']'+'SET'+' '+@COLUMN_NAME+
'=REVERSE(EXEC (@output))'

EXEC(@UPDATE_EXEC)
```

But I'm getting these errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@output"

Comment: You can not put EXEC inside any query.

Comment: SET @UPDATE_EXEC = 'UPDATE ['+@TABLE_Name + ']'+'SET'+' '+@COLUMN_NAME+
'=REVERSE('+@COLUMN_NAME+')'

Comment: @AnilAgrawal  Please put your answers as actual answers and not comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to put EXEC in your update query, its not allowed. EXEC is use to execute the query, it can't be part of any query.

To reverse any column in your table you can do so like below,

> SET @UPDATE_EXEC = 'UPDATE ['+@TABLE_Name + ']'+'SET'+' '+@COLUMN_NAME+ '=REVERSE('+@COLUMN_NAME+')';
>
> EXEC(@UPDATE_EXEC);